# Laravel 7 can't install laravel voyager

Tags: composer-php, php-7, laravel-7, voyager

when i want to install laravel voyager, with composer :

```
composer require tcg/voyager
```

> it returns this error when php.ini memory_limit = 128M :

```
   Using version ^1.4 for tcg/voyager
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for gloudemans/shoppingcart ^2.6 -> satisfiable by gloudemans/shoppingcart[2.6.0].
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v7.16.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.16.1
    - gloudemans/shoppingcart 2.6.0 requires illuminate/events 5.1.* || 5.2.* || 5.3.* || 5.4.* || 5.5.*|| 5.6.* || 5.7.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/events[5.1.x-dev, 5.2.x-dev, 5.3.x-dev, 5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9].
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.4.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.16.1
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.5.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.16.1
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.6.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.16.1
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.7.17|don't install laravel/framework v7.16.1
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.7.18|don't install laravel/framework v7.16.1
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.7.19|don't install laravel/framework v7.16.1
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.7.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.16.1
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.4.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.16.1
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.4.13|don't install laravel/framework v7.16.1
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.4.17|don't install laravel/framework v7.16.1
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.4.19|don't install laravel/framework v7.16.1
```

> and this error when php.ini memory_limit = -1 :

```
Using version ^1.4 for tcg/voyager
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 134217736 bytes) in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSet.php on line 84

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 134217736 bytes) in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSet.php on line 84

Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors for more info on how to handle out of memory errors.
```

the capacity of my laptop :

```
windows 10                    
processor : AMD A9-9420 RADEON R5? 5 COMPUTE CORES 2C+3G 3.00 GHz
RAM : 4.00 Go
system type : operating system 64 bits
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty clear:

```
- Installation request for gloudemans/shoppingcart ^2.6 -> satisfiable by gloudemans/shoppingcart[2.6.0].
- Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v7.16.1
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.16.1
- gloudemans/shoppingcart 2.6.0 requires illuminate/events 5.1.* || 5.2.* || 5.3.* || 5.4.* || 5.5.*|| 5.6.* || 5.7.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/events[5.1.x-dev, 5.2.x-dev, 5.3.x-dev, 5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9].
```

Even the latest version of `gloudemans/shoppingcart` is not compatible with Laravel v6 or v7, but `tcg/voyager` in v1.4 requires at least Laravel v6.

You should either look for a replacement for that shoppingcart package, or install Voyager in an older version that is compatible with Laravel v5. For example, v1.3 is compatible and can be installed using

`composer require tcg/voyager "^1.3"`

Comment: i use this : and solved : 
        "tcg/voyager": "1.5.2.*"

Answer (score 0):

I face same issue lets try this ,

Step 1. restart your system

Step 2. run `composer global require laravel/installer`

Step 3. Create fresh laravel project using
`composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog`

avoid to use `laravel new blog`

Step 4. change terminal path to project folder and run
`composer require tcg/voyager`

next follow [voyager docs](https://voyager-docs.devdojo.com/getting-started/installation)